# Como dividir dois valores de um array?

Tags: php, ajax, array

Tenho o seguinte código, onde apenas o índice 0 é string:

```
        $row[0] = $row[0];
        $row[1] =(float) $row[1];
        $row[2] =(float) $row[2];
        $row[3] =(float) $row[3];
        $row[4] =(float) $row[4];
        $row[5] =(float) $row[5];
        $row[6] =(float) $row[6];
```

Preciso dividir um índice pelo outro, estou tentando assim:

```
       $a = $row[5] / $row[6];
        $row[7] =$a;
```

Porém, minha tabela não carrega.
 
***Obs: O mais estranho é que se eu fizer uma soma ele funciona.***

O que esta ocorrendo?

Comment: Alguma divisão por zero?

Comment: @rray, sim alguns valores são 0.

Comment: Você quer automatizar isso com um laço de repetição por exemplo ? ou apenas dividir os valores que você escolher ? não ficou muito claro seu objetivo , poderia dar um exemplo de valores pra variavel `$row` para testar aqui

Comment: Da um "print_r($row[5] / $row[6]);" ve se retorna algum erro e coloca aqui.

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori, basicamente eu preciso fazer um calculo de porcentagem, que seria $row[2] + $row[3] + $row[5]   = $total, depois somar $row[2] + $row[5] / $total.

Comment: Você tem que criar por exemplo um `if` caso o divisor  `$row[2] + $row[5] / $total // <- $total é o divisor;` for igual a zero pular essa conta, pq de acordo com as regras da matematica não se pode dividir por 0

Comment: @VictorPereira , esta dando erro de divisão por 0

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori, creio que seja isso mesmo, vou tentar.

Comment: Qual a lógica disso: $row[0] = $row[0]; ?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho, é pra montar as linhas do DataTable. https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql

Comment: @GabrielTobias faz sentido seu primeiro trecho de código? Você está atribuindo a posição do array a mesmo coisa!

Comment: O que significam essas divisões e os valores em si ? Isso parece me um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)

Comment: @Isac, é um cálculo de performance de produção.

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori, realmente, o problema era a divisão por 0, fiz a condição e funcionou. Obrigado a todos pelas respostas!